# how do i generate a signature from given input and a secret key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, https, hmac, aws-secrets-manager

I'm trying to use AWS api to get keys from Secrets Manager using an internal linux server (using cURL). now i constructed a postman payload that works, but i noticed that the signature digest is changing with every request (because the time is also changing in the request). I tried to recreate this myself using an online hmac-sha256 generator tool, but i cant seem to create the correct payload to make the signatures match, even if i simply copy postman's http generated payload. this is my http payload according to postman:

```
POST https://secretsmanager.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: secretsmanager.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Target: secretsmanager.GetSecretValue
Accept-Encoding: identity
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: beaead3198f7da1e70d03ab969765e0821b24fc913697e929e726aeaebf0eba3
X-Amz-Date: 20220809T093728Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=credentils/20220809/eu-central-1/secretsmanager/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=signature
Content-Length: 98

{
    "SecretId": "arn:aws:secretsmanager:eu-central-1:rest-of-arn"
}
```

hashing it with my secret key (hmac-sha256) just doesnt output the same signature as the one in the payload - and the request fails.
anyone knows how to construct the correct payload to make this work?

Comment: I presume you are asking this beause you don't/can't install the aws cli.
That said, seems that curl supports [aws v4 signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html) with the [--aws-sigv4](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--aws-sigv4) option.

Answer (score 0):

The signature is supposed to change as the timestamp of the request is included in the *"string to sign"* in the [second step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-create-string-to-sign.html) of the [aws v4 signature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html).

As you can see, the signing process is quite complex and my suggestion is to avoid trying to re-implement it in a prod environment.

Instead, if you can, install the [aws cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/getting-started-install.html) or update curl to a version that supports [aws v4 signature](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#--aws-sigv4_).